# Clicking anywhere on the page besides the 3 menu items hide any visible menu item

Tags: javascript, html, css

1.Clicking anywhere on the page besides the 3 menu items
hide any visible menu item
2.When user clicks hamburger icon, side menu should be displayed
3.When user clicks “close” button in side menu, it should be hidden again

```
    <ul class="nav">
    <li id="menu-1-button">Why Slack?</li>
    <li id="menu-2-button">Solutions</li>
    <li id="menu-3-button">Resources</li>
    <li>Pricing</li>
    </ul>
    </section>
    <div class="nav-right">
    <p class="workspaces">Your Workspaces</p>
    <div class="hamburger-menu" id="menu-trigger">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2522641/hamburger.svg" 
    alt="Hamburger icon">
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>

    <!--Main content-->
    <section class="placeholder"></section>

    <!--Side menu-->
    <aside class="side-menu-position side-menu-design" id="side-menu">
    <header class="side-menu-header">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2522641/slack.svg" 
    alt="Slack logo">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2522641/x.svg" alt="Close 
   this menu" id="menu-close">
   </header>
   <ul class="side-menu-content">
   <li>Why Slack?</li>
   <li>Pricing</li>
   <li>About Us</li>
   <li class="side-menu-workspace">Your Workspaces</li>
   <li class="side-menu-download">Download Slack</li>
   </ul>
  </aside>


  <aside class="dropdown-menu" id="menu-1">
  <h2 class="menu-header">About the Product</h2>
  <ul class="menu-item-list">
  <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Enterprise</a></li>
  </ul>
  </aside>

 <aside class="dropdown-menu" id="menu-2">
 <h2 class="menu-header">Slack for Every Team</h2>
 <ul class="menu-item-list">
 <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Customer Support</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
 </ul>
 </aside>

 <aside class="dropdown-menu" id="menu-3">
 <h2 class="menu-header">Go Further With Slack</h2>
 <ul class="menu-item-list">
 <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Help Center</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">e-Books</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">API</a></li>
 </ul>
 </aside>
```

1.Clicking anywhere on the page besides the 3 menu items
hide any visible menu item
2.When user clicks hamburger icon, side menu should be displayed
3.When user clicks “close” button in side menu, it should be hidden again

Comment: What are you asking? This doesn't tell us what your problem is. We are not here to make the code for you, this platform is only here to help people fix their problems. You haven't even given us your CSS and JavaScript, so how can we help if you give us nothing to work with.

Comment: yes i haven't given the css and javascript because i wasn't able to to place it in the question section.

Comment: Use the snippet button in the wysiwyg